# Ace-like editor with setLine()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax-highlighting, ace-editor

Is there any Ace-like code editor that lets you set just one line at a time?
I tried Ace, but ran into issues when rapidly setting it's value; is there an editor that lets you set one line at a time? I rarely need to set the entire editor at once, but I need to refresh one line in particular very rapidly.

Comment: what kind of errors did you find, you should report an issue on https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace.

Comment: No actual errors; the browser just couldn't keep up with the constant updating to and from an SQL database, causing certain parts of the code to overwrite themselves and duplicate endlessly.

Comment: It maybe because of the way you were setting lines, could you add the snippet of code you were using, i can fix it for you.

Comment: `HTMLeditor.getSession().setValue(xml.responseText, 1);`

Comment: Ace just couldn't keep up with my refreshing the HTMLeditor from a server multiple times per second. I figured if setting so much text lagged it out, I could just set one line at a time, which is all I need to do anyway.

Comment: do you need to remove old line or just insert a new one at the end? Also do you want to keep undo history?

Answer (score 0):

In Ace you can use `session.insert` and `session.remove` methods. E.g to insert line at the end use

```
editor.session.insert({row: editor.session.getLength(), column: 0}, "line" + "\n")
```